# How to use object spread reduxjs/toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to implement @reduxjs/toolkit into my project and currently I'm facing problem with using spread operator

```
const initialState: AlertState = {
  message: '',
  open: false,
  type: 'success',
};

const alertReducer = createSlice({
  name: 'alert',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setAlert(state, action: PayloadAction<Partial<AlertState>>) {
      state = {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload,
      };
    },
  },
});
```

When I'm assigning state to new object my store doesn't update.
But if I change reducer to code

```
state.message = action.payload.message || state.message;
state.open = action.payload.open || state.open;
```

But that's not very handy. So is there way to use spread operator?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this case, you should return the new object from the function instead:

```
    setAlert(state, action: PayloadAction<Partial<AlertState>>) {
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload,
      };
    },
```

You can examine more examples in the [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#direct-state-mutation).
Also, be aware of this rule:

> you need to ensure that you either mutate the state argument or return a new state, but not both.

Comment: Took me hours to understand that I was mixing mutation and doing a new state with spread operator. According to the low number of views on this question, I'm afraid there's still people searching for the solution 

Comment: thanks a million for this answer and explanation. I never understood this, and it was never clear from the standard documentation for me. 
Kudo's for ever. ;-)